# Interactive color/text format on RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Is there a way to change the fill color of a row in an RDLC report based on a user click?  For example, if a user clicks a certain text box, the text box action would add or remove a highlight from the row.  I'm thinking I need to create an array and store the highlight switch for each row, but I'm not sure how I would update it after the report loads.

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2013.

EDIT: I should clarify that I can't make changes to the ReportViewer or any other files on the server.  The RDLC file is pretty much my only vessel for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. At least, not without refreshing the data each time a click happens. I have the feeling, that is not what you want to do.

The textboxes in RDL based reports do not have the events built into them that you need to make this happen. There are a few actions that can be taken when an end user clicks a textbox, but they are limited to going to a URL, another report, or a bookmark in the current report. But, you cannot run a Background setter expression, or code, when a click occurs.

Something I think people sometimes forget about when dealing with SSRS/RDL[C] is the fact that the deliverable is a report, not a full application. What you desire is heading more toward the application end of the spectrum.  Something checklist like.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to squeeze every bit of interface capability out of the report because I'm developing on a third party platform; this is the best option available to me.

I'll also be performing a data update, so refreshing the report isn't the end of the world.  It just means I'll probably have to create a SQL table to cache the initial recordset and query the "update" results off of that.  I just wondered if maybe it were possible to use the URL action to maybe run javascript or a VB function that would update the fill color while also returning "#" for the URL.  Thanks for the answer.